# undesired heart emojis in textview

Tags: android, encoding, emoji

Currently in my app users tend to send messages about time a lot. As a result in a conversation someone can send something like `10:30` and it will automatically displayed as `10❤️0`in my app. The `:3` gets converted to `❤️`in any of my `TextView`.

I'm not sure where to configure that (encoding related?), or is it a common problem on Android?

Comment: Arent the user clicking the emoji right the way?

Comment: Try changing the input type of the TextView so it only handles certain characters. Also look into add a textwatcher and looking for certain characters that get parsed into emoji characters (This is could be very tedious but since your use case is only for data strings it might not be to bad).